# How to Add two white random gaussian noises from different noise sources?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, signal-detection

I have generated two different white gaussian random noises in MATLAB using two different seeds. For example:

Asn1 =   sqrt(noisepow1/2)* (randn(size(As))+1i*(randn(size(As))));
Asn2 =   sqrt(noisepow2/2)* (randn(size(As))+1i*(randn(size(As))));

Here, noisepow1 and noisepow2 are amplitudes of noise powers, As is signal array.

I will need to add these two noises to calculate the SNR. As the two noises are from different sources, I am confused about how to add these two noise signals.
I can't simply just add Asn1 and Asn2 to calculate the total noise, because some signal samples will have opposite phases. Should I take the RMS of the amplitudes and add it with the phase term? I am confused about the addition operation of these two white Gaussian random noise signals. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I know there are a lot of knowledgeable people here ( definitely not my intention to criticize the quality of cross-validated. I've learned a ton from many talented people )  but  I think you'd get a greater response and more of a DSP natured response if you asked this on dsp.stackexchange.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/75728/235) on dsp.SE where it has already received an answer,